# Managing a dynamic form and updating a database in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, forms, codeigniter, dynamic

I have a database with a number of tables, `dbtable`.

I'm creating a form with php and I layout the form using `<table>`.

Each `<tr>` in the table corresponds to one row in a `dbtable`.

So, the more rows in a `dbtable`, the more tr-tags.. you get it.

My question is:

How should I name the input-tags to be able to use the POST-variables to update the database accordingly?

At the moment, I'm naming them `1_name, 2_name, 3_name` for one dbtable data
then `1_1_valueA, 1_1_valueB, 1_2_valueA, 1_2_valueB` for data that belongs to 1_name, 2_name etc.

But I feel this is not such a good approach..

Comment: Put database schema with sample data, the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

name them like this:

```
item[0][db_row_id]
item[0][value_a]
item[0][value_b]

item[1][db_row_id]
item[1][value_a]
item[1][value_b]
```

where the numbers 0 and 1 etc are just assigned as indicies in a POST array

you will be able to retrieve all of the items with `$_POST['item']`

or in CI `$this->input->post('item')`

and it will look like this:

```
array(
 array('db_row_id'=>val,'value_a'=>val,'value_b'=>val),
 array('db_row_id'=>val,'value_a'=>val,'value_b'=>val)
)
```

Comment: This works wonders! However, how do I name the input-tags in order to create a 2D-array? I have arbitrarily many headers with arbitrarity many sub-items... `name="item[0][1][valueA]"` for header number 1 and sub-item number 2, and `name="item[0][header]"` for the number 1 header input?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. You may want to post it as a new question with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="reords[0]['Name']" />
<input name="reords[0]['Age']" />
<input name="reords[0]['City']" />

<input name="reords[1]['Name']" />
<input name="reords[1]['Age']" />
<input name="reords[1]['City']" />
```

you can access data in sever side by

```
$this->input->post('reords');
```

it is an array like this

```
array(array('Name'=>'post val','Age'=>'post val','City'=>'post val'),
      array('Name'=>'post val','Age'=>'post val','City'=>'post val')
  )
```

you can use codegniter `upadte_batch` to add these records to db

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html